# Call class child component method from parent functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have two components:

Parent.js

```
import React from 'react
import Child from './Child'

function Parent() {

return (
    <div> 
         <Child />
         <button onClick={invoke child method onClick} > Button </button>
    </div>
 )
}

export default Parent
```

Child.js

```
import React from 'react

class Child extends Component {

getAlert() {
    console.log("called from parent")
}

render() {
    return (
        <div> 
          This is from child
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Child
```

Now, I want to call **getAlert()** method from parent component we can say i want to call a child method from parent. ***Please notice Parent is functional and child is class.***

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Components are not "instantiated" like that, so you don't really have a reference to the component to invoke methods on. What you should instead do is pass down a function or whatever you would like to the child component through it's props, which the child component can then use.

Comment: Why does the method live in the child if the parent needs to access it?

Comment: Because getAlert() will perform action on child component data. It's just a prototype.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: @sayalok Nope here child and parent are of same type. functional-functional and class-class. Here is difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.

```
import React from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

function Parent() {
  const handleAlert=(paramfn?:any)=>{
     if(paramfn){
         paramfn();
     }
  }

return (
    <div> 
         <Child onAlert={handleAlert} />
         <button onClick={invoke child method onClick} > Button </button>
    </div>
 )
}

export default Parent
```

> **`/*********Child**********/`**

```
import React from 'react'

class Child extends Component {

getAlert() {
    console.log("called from parent")
}

render() {
    return (
        <div onClik ={()=>this.props.onAlert(getAlert);}> 
          This is from child
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Child
```

Comment: As far as I can see You are invoking the child method by clicking on the div of child. Just passing the method as argument for parent method( onAlert ) and executing in parent. But what I want is click in parent and execute in child. Let us suppose child is a  drawer which is hidden for now, Then how will you click on div(This is from child) and invoke method.

Comment: It is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent